# Как склеить строки ?

Tags: perl, shell, sed, linux

Вопрос в заголовке.

Только не все строки. Про `tr -d '\n'` мне известно.

Пример:

```
abc
;
fgh
;
"
qwe
rty
"
;
"
asd
"
;
end
```

В конвейере нужно превратить в:

```
abc;fgh;"qwe
rty";"asd";end\r
```

Другими словами, сделать нормальный CSV из вывода, где поля в отдельных строках, разделитель полей ';' тоже в отдельной строке и поля, которые могут содержать \n, обрамлены строками '"'. Последний \n надо заменить на \r\n

Для программы (на Си?) я бы  сформулировал задачу просто:

убрать все \n вне "...", а внутри "..." убрать первый сразу за '"'. (на Си писать не надо, если "однострочник" не получится, то на нем сам как-нибудь напишу).

...

Пока замер на проблеме, что я никак не могу заставить работать что-нибудь типа

```
s/\n;\n/;/
```

ни в sed, ни в perl (т.е. работать с выражением для 2-х строк)

P.S.

python 2.4 тоже подойдет.

Comment: У меня вот так кое что получается, `sed 'N;s/\n//;N;s/\n//;N;s/\n//;'` но всеровно не доконца ) Блин задачка интересная, но спать хочется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -0777 -lpe 'BEGIN{$\="\r\n"}s#\n;\n#;#gsm;s#;"\n#;"#gsm'
```

Comment: Круть, вот тока rty";"asd";end\r у автора в одной строке :р

Comment: я знаю, но автор написал "убрать все \n вне "...", а внутри "..." убрать первый сразу за '"'."
где верить?

Comment: @arto, спасибо!!! Круто, просто магия!

Если бы Вы описали словами, что каждый символ в этом чудесном выражении означает (*особенно -0777*), было бы совсем хорошо.

--

Я немного изменил (конечно, совсем не так элегантно (к сожалению)), получилось так:


    perl  -0777 -lpe 's#\n;\n#;#gsm;s#;"\n#;"#gsm' |
       tr '\n' '\a' | cat -v | # в одну строку с ^G вместо \n
       sed 's/\^G"/"/g' |      # перенесем наверх закрывающие "
       sed 's/\^G$/\r\n/' |    # последнее поле \r\n 
       sed 's/\^G/\n/g'        # восстановим \n в "..."

Теперь, конечно, надо проверять на реальных данных.

Comment: -0777 -- прочитать всё в память
если надо убрать \n до ", то добавить s#\n";#";#gsm

# perl -0777 -pe 'BEGIN{$\="\r\n"}s#\n;\n#;#gsm; s#;"\n#;"#gsm; s#\n";#";#gsm'
abc
;
fgh
;
"
qwe
rty
"
;
"
asd
"
;
end^D
abc;fgh;"qwe
rty";"asd";end

Comment: @arto, т.е. -0777 говорит перлу, что выражения в программе применяются не к каждой строке по отдельности, а ко всему тексту?

Тогда уж скажите, о чем говорят флаги (или это команды?) **-l** и **-p**?

Без -l работает, а без -p -- нет.

Я правильно понимаю, что в программе сейчас 3 выражения для замены? Их порядок важен?  И что означают символы `sm` после `g` (я думаю g означает, что команда `s` действует по всему тексту)?

--

Кстати, последний вариант все равно делает в конце `\n\r\n`, а нужно `\r\n` и если поток заканчивается 

    "
    xxx
    "

то получаем

    "xxx
    "

Comment: @arto, небольшое экспериментирование показало, что

    perl -0777 -pe 's#\n;\n#;#g; s#;"\n#;"#g; s#\n";#";#g; s/\n$/\r\n/'

почти работает (исключение когда последнее поле в кавычках, но это можно пережить).

--

Также выяснил, что прядок выражений важен. Можно ли считать, что логически они просто выполняются над всем текстом друг за другом? Т.е. эквивалентная запись это 

    perl -0777 -pe 'expr1' | perl -0777 -pe 'expr2' | ...


Или после замены \\n;\\n дальше -0777 уже не нужно?

--

Кстати, не сразу догадался что `#` это просто знак-разделитель в выражении замены (необычно).

Comment: @avp: вместо `#` можно использовать и привычный `/`.

Comment: @VladD, про `/` я уже понял. 

Похоже, что окончательная (хотелось бы...) версия


    sed '/^$/d'  | 
      perl -0777 -pe 's/\n;\n/;/g;  s/\n$/\r\n/;  s/;$/\r\n/;  s/"\n/"/g;  s/\n"/"/g'

получилась такой. 

Работает, даже если в конце будет лишний разделитель полей `;`. А пустые строки внутри "...." все равно в Excel никому не нужны.

--

Вот про -0777 надо просто запомнить, что читает весь текст, а не обрабатывает по строкам.

--

А зачем нужен флаг `-e`, если без `-p` он не работает -- не понимаю.

Comment: Хочу тоже сказать спасибо +1 @arto, так как я пытался все сделать на sed, но не успел IQ не хватило :)